# How do I change an existing Xcode target from dynamic to static?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm working with an existing project that produces a dynamic library (Cocoa API).

I'd rather generate a static library, but if I change the 
[Linking|Mach-O Type] field from "Dynamic Library" to "Static Library",
both the Clean Project and Build Project complain that the
target has an invalid `MACH_O_TYPE` value of 'staticlib'.

Is there a straightforward way to get the build to produce
a static .a file?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 23):

Opens up the **project.pbxproj** file in **YourProjectName.xcodeproj** folder using TextEdit, search for **productType** and change it's value from "**com.apple.product-dynamic**" to "**com.apple.product-static**"

Comment: in my case it's **com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic** to be changed into **com.apple.product-type.library.static**. Maybe it's a different xcode version, I suggest to create a new static lib project and copy productType from there

Comment: For Xcode 9: static library is `com.apple.product-type.library.static`, dynamic library is `com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic`, framework is `com.apple.product-type.framework`, generic bundle is `com.apple.product-type.bundle`, unit testing bundle is `com.apple.product-type.bundle.unit-test`, application is `com.apple.product-type.application`, and command-line tool is `com.apple.product-type.tool`. There are many more, but these are by far the most common

Answer (score 4):

I ended up creating a new 'static library' project, and then added all 
the members.  Closing xcode and bringing up the two project files in
a text editor let me quickly complete the new project.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the correct solution.  There's currently no way to convert a target from one target type to another.

Comment: @cdespinosa You can change a library target from dynamic to static. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this, with the help of this post and a bit of digging around.  Additional changes I had to make were changing **compiled.mach-o.dylib** to **archive.ar** and changing various references in the project file (including inside comments, call me pedantic) from **foo.dylib** to **libfoo.a**.

I also had to create a new 'scheme' before it would build, but that might be because I changed the name of the project, I'm not sure.  Also, any frameworks referenced by the library need to be added to the application(s) that link against it when you move from .dylib to .a.

It was well worth persevering though as it preserved all the subtleties of the original project (such as building a 32/64 fat binary for release but not for debugging).  Result.

Comment: Been a long time since I logged this, but you get an upvote for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your build target, then create a new one, choose "Library" and make sure you choose type "Static". After this, you only have to add your sources and dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change two settings:

- Under Library, set Mach-O Type to Static Library
- Under Packaging, set Executable Extension to `a`

This worked for me on Xcode 13.1.