# How to solve Unknown layer type in Caffe IOS.?

Tags: ios, iphone, static, caffe

1.I download source from https://github.com/aleph7/caffe/ and builded the caffe as static library for IOS and IPhone.
2.Created sample demo code and Linked Caffe static lib(.a) and execute the code.
3.Now I got Run time error

F0519 14:54:12.494139 14504 layer_factory.hpp:77] Check failed: registry.count(t ype) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown layer type: Convolution (known types: MemoryData)

4.I searched a lot and found one solution from below link

[Caffe layer creation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325108/caffe-layer-creation-failure)

5.If I create dynamic library instead of static library. It will work.

6.I tried to convert static library into Dynamic library.I got Error on Xcode that is cannot open the project I referred below link.

[How do I change an existing XCode target from dynamic to static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349115/how-do-i-change-an-existing-xcode-target-from-dynamic-to-static)

Can you help how to solve this..?

Comment: Try also asking in Caffe Google's users group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/caffe-users

Answer (score -1):

Caffe register layer classes through `REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS` macro. Some build tools (e.g. Xcode) will optimize some part of it out (a little complex to explain). You can add `-Wl,-force_load path/to/libcaffe.a` to the `Other Linker Flags` build option. It will force Xcode to load all the things in libcaffe.a to the final target.

And more, `Unknown layer type` error can also caused by stale code. The caffe code in https://github.com/aleph7/caffe/ is out of date. You can try my port at https://github.com/solrex/caffe-mobile. It inlcudes a demo iOS app, works with the newest build tool. The Caffe source is up to date and you can sync the latest caffe code your self.